# How to overplot fit results for discrete values in pymc3?

Tags: python, bayesian, pymc3

I am completely new to pymc3, so please excuse the fact that this is likely trivial.  I have a very simple model where I am predicting a binary response function.  The model is almost a verbatim copy of this example: https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3/blob/master/pymc3/examples/gelman_bioassay.py

I get back the model parameters (alpha, beta, and theta), but I can't seem to figure out how to overplot the predictions of the model vs. the input data.  I tried doing this (using the parlance of the bioassay model):

```
 from scipy.stats import binom

 mean_alpha = mean(trace['alpha'])
 mean_beta = mean(trace['beta'])

 pred_death = binom.rvs(n, 1./(1.+np.exp(-(mean_alpha + mean_beta * dose))))
```

and then plotting dose vs. pred_death, but this is manifestly not correct as I get different draws of the binomial distribution every time.

Related to this is another question, how do I evaluate the goodness of fit?  I couldn't seem to find anything to that effect in the "getting started" pymc3 tutorial.

Thanks very much for any advice!

Answer (score 1):

Hi a simple way to do it is as follows:

```
from pymc3 import *
from numpy import ones, array

# Samples for each dose level
n = 5 * ones(4, dtype=int)
# Log-dose
dose = array([-.86, -.3, -.05, .73])


def invlogit(x):
    return np.exp(x) / (1 + np.exp(x))



with Model() as model:

    # Logit-linear model parameters
    alpha = Normal('alpha', 0, 0.01)
    beta = Normal('beta', 0, 0.01)

    # Calculate probabilities of death
    theta = Deterministic('theta', invlogit(alpha + beta * dose))

    # Data likelihood
    deaths = Binomial('deaths', n=n, p=theta, observed=[0, 1, 3, 5])
    start = find_MAP()
    step = NUTS(scaling=start)
    trace = sample(2000, step, start=start, progressbar=True)




import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

death_fit = np.percentile(trace.theta,50,axis=0)

plt.plot(dose, death_fit,'g', marker='.', lw='1.25', ls='-', ms=5, mew=1)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to plot dose vs pred_death, where pred_death is computed from the mean estimated values of alpha and beta, then do:

```py
pred_death = 1./(1. + np.exp(-(mean_alpha + mean_beta * dose)))
plt.plot(dose, pred_death)
```

instead if you want to plot dose vs pred_death, where pred_death is computed taking into account the uncertainty in posterior for alpha and beta. Then probably the easiest way is to use the function `sample_ppc`:

May be something like

ppc = pm.sample_ppc(trace, samples=100, model=pmmodel)

```
for i in range(100):
    plt.plot(dose, ppc['deaths'][i], 'bo', alpha=0.5)
```

Using Posterior Predictive Checks (ppc) is a way to check how well your model behaves by comparing the predictions of the model to your actual data. [Here](https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3/blob/6bbb7911787fa664373e88ae9bd0def2e5b4f7ed/pymc3/examples/notebooks/posterior_predictive.ipynb) you have an example of `sample_ppc`

Other options could be to plot the mean value plus some interval of interest.